# Specifying choices for SQL table data types - sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-types

I'm working on setting up a table where one of the requirements is that a column should be "gender" and the data it accepts should be either "M" or "F". How do I specify this condition?

```
CREATE TABLE bears (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  name TEXT,
  age INTEGER,
  gender ("M" or "F")
)
```

Comment: I know that there are ways to do in SQL but why not enforce this condition using the language that you are calling the SQL with? This generally give you more flexibility in case you want to change the constraints (idk add a newly discovered gender maybe)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One simple method is a `check` constraint:

```
create table t as (
    . . .,
    gender char(1) not null,
    constraint chk_t_gender check (gender in ('M', 'F'))
);
```

Note that SQLite ignores the `(1)` on the character type, but the `check` constraint enforces the length.  Written in this way, the code follows standard SQL.